# How can I make a Sankey diagram for data vis for showing my data?

Tags: visualization, sankey-diagram

So I have 5 years of data that I want to make 5 different sankey diagrams for using JS and preferably from Echarts library.

I already have added a code and I'm using the echarts library already. But the data vis looks really mundane and isn't even showing the real numbers in the data.

I want to add a swipe to next sankey-feature in there as well where the data will move back year by year. I want to add the Sankey charts data separately on my dashboard but my current one isn't showing any actual data and showing the real numbers on cursor.